# How to check if input field is large enough to display full content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using a [Vuetify text-field](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/) component inside a table with many columns. It is possible that this component contains too much content to be displayed and from a UX perspective it takes too much time to check the content by scrolling inside the field if there are many cells.

[Plain HTML example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNo9jjFuwzAMRa/yq8Xt0BpdCyVAt9wgi5bApmMBEilIdJDA8N3DJEDGx/dJ/tX9l/JzWcj9Od+GGouikS5lHzjmIlWxotKEDVOVjM6iXeDAg3BT5HbG7uE/uwOlJDhKTeMHVAR5GWZYTIkVkaFzbFC6KqZIaTRl9/khVTDGVtLp1n0F9v2rhzUwUMomlIwAP//u1/X5ddt8b/ScRi6L4vKdZaS0C858cKZ8/9522x0EPlJb)

[Vuetify example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

My first idea ( please let me know if you know better ones ) was to display a tooltip showing the full content but this would be annoying if the component is able to display the full content. So I only want to display the tooltip if content would be hidden/cut off.

So is there a way to get to know if the component is displaying the full content or if something is hidden/cut off? ( Table performance is important so I don't know if very complex calculations on value changes are worth it )

I tried

( [Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) )

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

  const field = ref()
  const msg = ref(
    'Hello World! too much content in this text field component to display.'
  )
  const isCuttingOff = ref(false)

  watch(
    msg,
    () => {
      const inputWidth = field.value?.clientWidth
      const inputValueWidth = msg.value.length // !!! measure the input value here !!!

      console.log({ inputWidth, inputValueWidth })

      isCuttingOff.value = inputWidth < inputValueWidth
    },
    { immediate: true }
  )
</script>

<template>
  <v-app>
    <div class="text-h3">Is cutting off: {{ isCuttingOff }}</div>
    <v-container class="w-25">
      <v-text-field ref="field" label="fsfdsf" v-model="msg" />
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

but

- on startup, the variable `inputWidth` is undefined
- I don't know how to calculate the variable `inputValueWidth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to compare textbox's `clientWidth` with its `scrollWidth` by modifying your code as below.

1- Got rid of `field` ref.

2- Gave `v-text-field` an id

3- added a `check` function and called it in `watch` callback function

4- inside `check` I checked input's `clientWidth` and `scrollWidth`

5- To get it to run in the initial load, I assigned an empty string to `msg` and changed it to the original string at the bottom of the script.

Check it [here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

  const msg = ref("")

  const isCuttingOff = ref(false)

  function check() {
    const elm = document.querySelector('#txt')
    isCuttingOff.value = elm.clientWidth < elm.scrollWidth;
    // todo : custom tooltip or any other solution for long texts
  }

  watch(
    msg,
    (currentMsg, oldMessage, callback) => {
      callback(check)
    },
    { immediate: true }
  )

  msg.value =
    'Hello World! too much content in this text cfield component to display.'
</script>
<script></script>
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div class="text-h3">Is cutting off: {{ isCuttingOff }}</div>
    <v-container class="w-25">
      <v-text-field id="txt" v-model="msg" />
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You just need ***title*** attribute and little ***css***

Using css to display the overflow of text like **....** (ellipsis) and **title** attribute is used to show the full content on hover like popup

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World! too much content in this text field component to display')
</script>

<template>
  <h1 :title=msg>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg">
</template>

<style>
  h1{
    max-width: 15rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried your snippet in the playground https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpFkLtug0AQRX/lhoakIBZFGoItpcsfpKFB7JBdaV/aHYwtxL9nMCiudnbO1czRLMVXjO/XiYqmaPOQTGRk4ileOm9cDImxINGIFWMKDqVEy853fgg+M1z+xXnjr+U3WRvwE5JVL+AQ4KZBQ2JMnmE8WJsMphtjNGSVIJnvN8gByuRo+3v51vn2tHuIgXwy3y1JCeh62R7A9bdqNop1g/ojkfvc27M2TFWO/UANfJhTHw8SrpRGG+YG2ihF/mhvLtWTib+J2eQHXR8ex26pmZz48W7S6hoNG7Z0lgNcluVxh3VtT7reA8bHiXGtXFBkz10hvCsEtaf/QcX6B/aVhDg= but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: I changed the code, now see @baitendbidz